# to make the form appear on button click in angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a  code written in angular4 where i want the form to appear only on button click i.e. on clicking the  "register" button . However, there appears a problem.  The button and the form both appear . I am making the form by model driven form method.I have three files app.component.js,app.module.js and app.component.html .please help.

Code is :
**app.component.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import {MyserviceService} from './servicecomponent/myservice.service'
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
 import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
  import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';


   @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })


  export class AppComponent {
 title = 'Angular 4 Project!';
  todaydate;
  componentproperty;
   searchparam = 2;

 name;

 email;
 age;
 lastname;
 mobilenumber;
 aadhaarnumber;
 formdata2 ;
 openform=false;



 constructor(private myservice: MyserviceService,private http: Http) 
   {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.todaydate = this.myservice.showTodayDate();
  console.log("date is",this.todaydate);
  console.log(this.myservice.serviceproperty);
  this.myservice.serviceproperty = "component created"; // value is 
   changed.
  this.componentproperty = this.myservice.serviceproperty;

  this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
  map((response) => response.json()).
  subscribe((data) => console.log(data));





    this.formdata2 = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl("", Validators.compose([
   Validators.required,
   Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")
 ])),
  name:new FormControl("",Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("[a-z]{1,8}")
  ])),
  lastname:new FormControl("",Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("[a-z]{1,4}")
  ])),
  age:new FormControl("",Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("[0-9]{2}")
  ])),
  mobilenumber:new FormControl("",Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("[0-9]{10}")
  ])),

  aadhaarnumber:new FormControl("",Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("[0-9]{12}")
  ]))

  });

  }

 onClickOpenForm(){
  this.openform=true;
  return this.openform;

  }


 onClickSubmitForm(data2){
 this.email=data2.email;
 this.age=data2.age;
 this.mobilenumber=data2.mobilenumber;
 this.aadhaarnumber=data2.aadhaarnumber;
 this.name=data2.name;
 this.lastname=data2.lastname;


    }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div>
  <button (click)="onClickOpenForm()" 
 value="Register">Register</button>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!onClickOpenForm()">
  <form [formGroup]="formdata2" 
  (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmitForm(formdata2.value)">
    Name:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="yourname" 
  placeholder="Your Name" formControlName="name">
    <br> LastName:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="yourlastname" 
 placeholder="Your Last Name" formControlName="lastname">
    <br> Age:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="yourage" 
 placeholder="Your Age" formControlName="age">
    <br> Email:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="youremail" 
 placeholder="Your Email" formControlName="email">
    <br> Mobile Number:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="yourmobile" 
 placeholder="Your Mobile Number" formControlName="mobilenumber">
    <br> Aadhaar Number:
    <input type="text" class="yourtextbox" name="youraadhaar" 
 placeholder="Your Aadhar Number" formControlName="aadhaarnumber">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" [disabled]="!formdata2.valid" type="button" 
class="btn btn-success" class="forsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
<br>
<br>
<p>
Name is :{{name}} Lastname is:{{lastname}}

</p>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { NewComponentComponent } from './new-component/new- 
  component.component';
 import { CateinaComponent } from './cateina-new-component/cateina- 
 new-component.component';
 import { MyserviceService } from 
 './servicecomponent/myservice.service';
 import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewComponentComponent,
    CateinaComponent,
   AppComponent,
   ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'new-cmp',
    component: NewComponentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'cateina-cmp',
    component: CateinaComponent
  },

  ])
  ],
 providers: [MyserviceService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Maybe add *ngIf="openform" in <form... tag? or on that upper div. Replace [hidden] with *ngIf="openform", onClickOpenForm function doesn't need to return value because you can access openform variable in the template and in component that's why its called two way data binding.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to make smaller examples focused on your concern to make it easier for other to help you.
Your problem is probably linked to the `[hidden]="!onClickOpenForm()"`, it looks like a bad copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down the fact that in your template, you have

```
[hidden]="!onClickOpenForm()"
```

and onClickOpenForm() does not track the state of whether the form should be shown, it sets your openform member to true, and returns it, i.e. it always returns true:

```
 onClickOpenForm(){
  this.openform=true;
  return this.openform;
  }
```

You should probably replace the [hidden] binding with:

[hidden]="!openform"

or possibly surround your form with:

```
<div *ngIf="openform">
  <!-- your form here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
<div [hidden]="!onClickOpenForm()">...
```

rather you should bind as :

```
<div [hidden]="!openform">...
```

it should work with

```
onClickOpenForm(){
  this.openform=true;  
  }
```